# drawing use case diagram for device driver

Tags: uml, linux-device-driver, device-driver, software-design

I'm trying to write use case diagram for a wireless NIC driver. There is no direct interaction of the user with the driver. How can one write use case diagram for drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the previos 2 answers with a bit more info and an example...

The key aspect of the use case model is its **context**, or the **system scope** (depicted with a Boundary element on the diagram itself - see example). Everything that is "inside" the scope is abstracted by a UC and everything from the "outside" is modelled by an actor (human or system). Use cases model the **interaction**, the **dialogue**, the **exchange of information between the two of them**.

I see at least two system actors in your case, a **controlled device** and a **client program**. Another possible actor has been added in the following example, to show some eventual periodic communication with the device through the driver:

[image]

This is a very nice example on how different UML diagrams play together to show the whole truth. UC diagram focuses on the meaningful interactions between the System and its environment, showing no technical info about it.

In order to do this you need another diagram (here **component**, but classes are also ok, even both). This diagram is the place to define interfaces, APIs, method signatures, dependencies...

You can of course go a step further and use a **sequence/interaction** diagram to connect the Use cases with the corresponding components (on my example are only shown the "traces" to clear up which actors are implemented by which components). Something like this:

[image]

Note that something called "Data" is sent to the Driver (and the Device). This can further be defined in a class diagram, making a whole new point of view on this system.

It is common practice to put all this info in use case description. Although this approach might even be syntatically correct, the full power of UML is released by separating the concerns in different diagrams, keeping each one as simple and clear as possible, focused on only one concern and clean of others.

Comment: Clear on how to write it now. Which tool did you use to draw the diagrams?

Comment: I'm glad. :) The tool is "Enterprise architect"

Answer (score 3):

The 'user' in a use case is not necessarily a person hitting keys or anything. It is an 'actor' external to the system being described who can interact with the system being described.

Here, such actors could include routers or other bits of hardware that your NIC wants to connect to or that want to connect to it; it includes the hardware and OS the NIC is plugged into which the NIC exchanges signals with; and devices it is connected to and the signals they exchange.

Use cases would include:

The NIC detects available routers....
The NIC receives a request from......

Et cetera, to cover what you want the NIC to do.

Comment: @Shashank page http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-actor.html gives some examples of the "user" in a use case

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario Actor is system. You can include a system into use case as an actor, if that system is **outside of the system** you are developing and if it **directly interacts with that system** you are developing.

You may also need to define boundary of your system, which means its scope and interfaces. For example: you may want to create an actor for Routers. Preferable actions would be how they will interact with the driver of yours, as they are directly interacting with the system you are developing.

Hope this helps.
If you need further explanation with example, please comment below.